# moving html element across the screen using requestAnimationFrame in javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, requestanimationframe

Please bear with me...
I am learning how to use requestAnimationFrame for simple animation (eg:move ball across the screen.) I got example working using javscript functions. Now I want to use javascript class and methods to do the same thing. I am doing this because next I want to instantiate class multiple times, run and control multiple balls moving across the screen. Issues:

1. Not sure if my class syntax is ideal. (It's a bit of a hack)
2. requestAnimationFrame is running animation too fast.

   `...animationRequest = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.moveBall());`

It works as javascript functions
https://jsfiddle.net/tjqbpv1e/

but goes too fast (or not at all) when I create a class.
https://jsfiddle.net/68vys0hL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some undeclared and extra variables as well as missing `this`, but other than that it looks like a decent class.
The reason why there is no animation (aka too fast), is because you are executing `this.moveBall()` directly instead of sending `this.moveBall` as callback to `requestAnimationFrame`. Also you don't have anything what would control the speed at all. With `requestAnimationFrame` you have to check how long it passed since previous callback, like you have in original code as unused `diff` variable.

Speaking of callbacks, it's a bit tricky sending callbacks with `this` scope, very often you might need `.bind(this)` to the callback function:

```js
class AnimatedCircle {

  output;
  animated_circle;
  number;
  xpos;
  multiplier;
  animationRequest;
  myContainer;
  screen_width;
  prevTime;
  speed;

  constructor(val_1, val_2) {
    this.val_1 = val_1;  // example of passing values
    this.val_2 = val_2;

    this.animated_circle = document.getElementById('animated_circle');
    this.number = 0;
    this.xpos = 1;                 // new horizontal position
    this.multiplier = 1;
    this.animationRequest = null;
    this.myContainer = document.querySelector('#container');
    this.screen_width = this.myContainer.offsetWidth - 50;
    this.prevTime = 0;
    this.speed = Math.random() * 10; //random speed
  }

  // test method
  test_method() {
    return `${this.val_1} says hello.`;
  }

  moveBall(time) {

    this.animationRequest = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.moveBall.bind(this));
    if (time - this.prevTime < this.speed) //speed control
      return;

    this.prevTime = time;

    // if on screen 
    console.log("got here!");
    if (this.xpos < this.screen_width && this.xpos > 0) {
      this.number++;
    }
    else {
      // when we get to end of screen , then exit function
      return;
    }

    this.xpos = this.xpos + (5);    // horizontal position

    // move on X-Axis
    this.animated_circle.style.transform = `translateX(${this.xpos}px)`;
    console.log("loop");

  }

}
// instantiate class
myAnimatedCircle = new AnimatedCircle('Bob', 'Level22');
// call method
console.log(myAnimatedCircle.test_method());
console.log(myAnimatedCircle.moveBall());
```

```css
#container{
            border: 1px solid gray;
            background-color: rgb(236, 225, 225);            
            height:60px;
            padding:0px;            
        }            
 #animated_circle{
            height: 35px;
            width: 35px;
            margin:10px;
            background-color: rgb(103, 74, 184);
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
    <div id="container" >
        <p id="animated_circle"></p>
    </div>
```